# Is there a version of the covariance matrix for binary variables?

Tags: categorical-data

I want to take an idea I saw in Modern Portfolio Theory and use it in a different context. The set up for modern portfolio theory can be seen here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory
I will provide some details however for the purpose of the post.

Suppose there exist stocks $1,...,k$. For each stock, $i$, there is a random variable $R_i$ denoting the return, where $R_i$ is the return on stock $i$. Let $w_i$ be the percentage of your total stock portfolio devoted to stock $i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k w_i=1$. Let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix between the $R_i$.

Ideally, we want a large return but we don't want it to fluctuate because then it can go down. So there's a trade off between minimizing variance and maximizing the expected return. Let $\mathbf{R}$ be a vector of the expected returns. This is captured by the following equation:

$$\min_{\mathbf{w}} \mathbf{w}^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{w}-q\mathbf{R}^T\mathbf{w}$$

where $q\geq 0$ is the "risk tolerance" and is fixed by the portfolio designer.

My question is, could I construct an analogous idea where the returns are binary variables?

Suppose instead of $R_i \in \Bbb{R}_+$ I had $R_{i} \in \lbrace 0, 1\rbrace$. Is there an analogous way to perform this optimization?

I looked into correlations between binary variables and I found two different measures

- **Phi coefficient:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient
- **Cramer's V:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V
- polychoric / tetrachoric correlation

But I've never used these so I'm uncertain if simply changing out $\Sigma$ and using a matrix with one of these measures instead would work. If $M$ was the "covariance" matrix using one of these other measures, would $\mathbf{w}^T M \mathbf{w}$ still be meaningful?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with writing the covariance of such a random variable, since your construction makes it clear that it is not a 'discrete' random variable, but a highly constrained continuous one.  I should note that $\Sigma$ takes a special form in the 'horse race' version of this problem when exactly one of the $R_i$ equals 1, something like $\operatorname{Diag}\left(\vec{\pi}\right) - \vec{\pi} \vec{\pi}^{\top}$.

Comment: Have you looked at the polychoric correlation? It assumes a normally distributed latent variable underlying the observed binary variable that has been dichotomized at a threshold to arrive at the observed variable. The polychoric correlation is the correlation between the latent continuous variables.

Comment: @steveo'america perhaps my writing isn't clear. I want to know about using a different form of  covariance or correlation specially for binary data not continuous data.

Comment: @Noah i have heard of it, but will that work in the context I am referring to? I'm trying to design an optimization problem that would allow me to minimize the covariance / correlation

Comment: @StanShunpike given that your portfolio weights are continuous, not discrete, I do not see the point. For large $k$ it will not end up mattering that the $R_i$ are somehow constrained to be in $\{0,1\}$.